# Prevent queries overwriting each other

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have application which receives car reservation requests, and on reservation car status in `cars` table should be set to `in_use`.

Normally something like this would be done:

```
def reserve_car(user_id)
  car = Car.find_by(status: 'available')
  car.update_columns(user_id: user_id, status: 'in_use')

  car
end
```

But this solution creates a gap between selecting available car and updating it's state and then dilemma occurs when app have to process relative large number of request so in same time few requests tries to reserve same car.

To reduce that risk I find and update available car in the same SQL query. Also I randomize available cars list order to reduce it even more. For randomizing the result I don't use `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` because AFAIK it generates random id for every record, sorts it and only when limits result to specified number - 1. Which isn't efficient because cars table expected to have large number of records in the future (100k+).

So I come up with this solution:

```
def reserve_car(user_id)
  sql = <<-SQL
    UPDATE
      cars AS r0,
      (
        SELECT
          r1.id
        FROM
          cars AS r1
          JOIN (
            SELECT
              (
                RAND() * (
                  SELECT
                    MAX(id)
                  FROM
                    cars
                )
              ) AS id
          ) AS r2
        WHERE
          r1.status = 'available'
          AND r1.id >= r2.id
        LIMIT
          1
      ) AS r3
    SET
      r0.status = 'in_use',
      r0.user_id = #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote(user_id)}
    WHERE
      r0.id = r3.id
  SQL

  updates = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_update(sql)

  car = Car.find_by(user_id: user_id, status: 'in_use')

  if car.present?
    car
  else
    raise "Failed to reserve car. Updates: #{updates}"
  end
end
```

But often enough I receive exception "Failed to reserve car. Updates 0" although for a fact I know there is plenty of available cars.

What could be wrong? Maybe someone could suggest a better solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what database is in use but most major DBs these days have a way to perform an update and return data from the row that was updated

For example, in oracle:

```
update car
set in_use = 1
where in_use = 0 and id = (select min(id) from car where in_use = 0)
returning id into car_id_that_was_set_in_use
```

The parameter car_id_that_was_set_in_use will contain the id of the car that was booked

As a single operation that establishes locks and doesn't hold a transaction open for a long time it shouldn't cause any contention

MySQL seems to be a notable exception to this - I don't find any indication that MySQL supports anything like `UPDATE..RETURNING` but there are other workarounds, such as innodb supporting `SELECT..FOR UPDATE` to allow you to lock the record you want to update, and hacks involving variables that might look something like:

```
 UPDATE car SET
     in_use = 1, id = @affectedid := id
 WHERE in_use = 0 AND id=(SELECT MIN(id) FROM car WHERE in_use = 0);
 SELECT @affectedid;
```

Test it though; I've never used this and adapted it from an SO answer

---

You can alternatively code your front end app to round-robin it, though it's less efficient. This is pseudocode, cos I don't do ruby:

```
int rowsupdated = 0
int potentialId = -1
while(rowsupdated = 0 and potentialId is not null) {
  potentialId = sql_scalar("SELECT MIN(id) FROM car WHERE in_use = 0")
  rowsupdated = sql_nonquery("UPDATE car SET in_use = 1 WHERE in_use = 0 and id = " + potentialId)
}
if(potentialId is null)
  //there was no car to book, we tried them all - potentialId would only be null if there were no more cars
else
  //potentialId now contains the id of the car we booked
```

The while loop will keep going until it books a car. It's naive and inefficient but it raises an important point, applicable to the previous query also

*The update query must reference the same value of in_use that we're still expecting*

You can't select an id, and just go ahead and set in_use = 1, without considering whether someone else has set in_use=1 while we were idle. This is called optimistic concurrency - you HOPE that noone else changed the data on the row you want to edit, but you include all the data you know about the row, so that if someone else DID change the row, the update fails and returns 0 records updated. The update fails if someone else set in_use = 1 while we were idle, and we make it a condition of the update that in_use still be 0 in order for the update to succeed.
If 0 is returned by the update, we can assume someone else changed the row before we did. Then, knowing we didn't get that row, we try for another one (or make a decision to overwrite/merge/accept the other person's changes)

Comment: Updated my question with mysql tag. Didn't thought about loop solution, though it's less efficient but much simpler and think it's reliable enough. I will implement it and see where it goes. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Rails with active record you should be able to lock the car record once you've found it to prevent it being retrieved by another request. 
Something like:

```
def reserve_car(user_id)
  car = Car.find_by(status: 'available')
  car.with_lock do
    car.update_columns(user_id: user_id, status: 'in_use')
  end

  car
end
```

You will probably need to tweak that according to the [ActiveRecord locking docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html)

Comment: Interesting, will look into it, thanks! What I currently done is: `Car.where(id: potential_car_id, status: 'available').limit(1).update_all(status: 'in_use')`. I fetch random potential_car_id from Car with status available and then try to update all records containing what ID and status 'available' in this case if another request reserved car with potential_car_id it will not be overwritten because condition status = 'available' would not be met. Like in answer was suggested.